# Decomposing surfaces into pairs of pants

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology

I apologise if this question is badly worded/doens't make sense - if I knew how to formulate this question well, I'd probably be half-way to answering it myself.

Let $F_g$ be a closed surface of genus $g$, for $g \geq 2$. Let K be a pants decomposition of our surface, i.e. a set of closed curves on $F_g$ such that when we cut along the curves, we obtain a number of disjoint pairs of pants. Furthermore, suppose all curves in K are geodesics on $F_g$.

Finally, suppose $F_g$ admits some hyperbolic metric.

Each pair of pants contains three seams, i.e. lines of shortest distance between each pair of boundary components.

**Question**: Suppose $P_i, P_j$ are two pairs of pants in $F_g$ which are glued along a common boundary component $\delta$. Do the end-points of the seams of $P_i$ in $\delta$ match up with the end-points of the seams of $P_j$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "almost never" because you can glue two pairs of pants along some circle with an $\mathbb{R}$ worth of twists.  Thus, if the seams do match up then doing some small $\epsilon$ twist will make it so they don't match anymore.

However, you can also note that for any of the three boundary components of a pair of pants, two of the seams hit it, and ask "If one pair of seams matches up, does the other match up as well?" and for this one I have no idea.